# Serving dynamically generated files as static files using Nginx

Tags: dynamic, static, nginx, php

Nginx is great at serving static files, so Im wondering is it possible to serve dynamically generated files as static files?

For example cloud we use [PHP Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to combine CSS & JS files on PHP-FPM behind Nginx and serve them almost like any static files, probably with some versioning & caching.

So its considered and behave more like static files then dynamic. I know it sounds more like caching but is thats how Nginx servers static files at its best?